# React Native Firebase authentication error handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

How to set state `('this.setState({})')` inside error handling function for Firebase auth?

its not working in React Native.

```
  onSignUpPress() {
    if (this.state.password !== this.state.passwordConfirmation ) {
      return this.setState({errorMessage: 'Your passwords do not match'});
    }

      ref.createUser({
        email    : this.state.email,
        password : this.state.password
      }, function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            // this.setState({errorMsg: error}) <-- Like this, it not work on React Native.
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rewriting the function using es6 fat arrow syntax. One issue for sure in the above code is that `this` is not bound to the correct scope. Try writing the function like this:

```
onSignUpPress() {
    if (this.state.password !== this.state.passwordConfirmation ) {
      return this.setState({errorMessage: 'Your passwords do not match'});
    }

      ref.createUser({
        email    : this.state.email,
        password : this.state.password
      },(error, authData) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({errorMsg: error})
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
        }
    });
  }
})
```